# How to redirect to different pages in react app based in the user login credentials? like there is same page for all the user and

Tags: reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code

redirect the user to different pages based on the username id creadential. like first we will check the first letter of username input and figure out the type of user they are and then check in the respective database table for authentication and then redirect them to page according to the type of  user they are . IN REACT NATIVE

Comment: Do you have any code to go by?

Comment: There is plenty of ways to do this though. You could store a object array with an object property being the different page locations in state and when you get the user type just reflect it off of that array with the corresponding object page location

Answer (score 0):

I. Just make auth functions somewhere like in utils. Generally the logic you required for redirection perpose.

II. Then you can use the Apploading component which gets rendered before the Login Screen. When user starts the app if the credentials are saved call `auth functions` which redirects the user related screen or screens.

else:  redirect to auth screen and after getting the credentials save them and call `auth functions` from there.

hope this helps. You have structure your navigation components.